# Java and Spring. Transactional annotation @Transactional

Tags: java, spring

I want to Remove begin and commit transactions from   DAO class , and I need to use Transactional annotation. How it should be done?
 Now , exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction

CoursesDAO.java

```
public interface CoursesDAO {

public Course createCourse(Course course);

public Course findCourseById(Integer key);

public Course updateCourse(Course course);

public void deleteCourse(Course course);

public List<Course> getAllCourses();

public List<Course> getAllCoursesByCategory(String category);

public List<Course> getAllCoursesWhichNoProposal( );

}
```

CoursesDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class CoursesDAOImpl implements CoursesDAO {

 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Course createCourse(Course course) {

     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    Integer id = (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(course);
    course.setId(id);
    //session.getTransaction().commit();

    return course;
};

public Course findCourseById(Integer id) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    Course course = (Course) session.get(Course.class, id);
    //session.getTransaction().commit();

    return course;
}


public Course updateCourse(Course course) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(course);
    //session.getTransaction().commit();

    return course;
};

public void deleteCourse(Course course) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(course);
    //session.getTransaction().commit();    



};

public List<Course> getAllCourses() {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    List listCourses = session.createQuery("from Course").list();
    //session.getTransaction().commit();
    return listCourses;
}



public List<Course> getAllCoursesByCategory(String category) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    List listCoursesByCategory = session.createQuery("from Course c where c.category='"+category+"'").list();
    //session.getTransaction().commit();

    return listCoursesByCategory;
}


public List<Course> getAllCoursesWhichNoProposal( ) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    List listCoursesNoProposal = session.createQuery("from Course c where c.state not like 'Proposal' and c.state not like 'Rejected'").list();
    //session.getTransaction().commit();

    return listCoursesNoProposal;
}

}
```

CourseService.java

```
public interface CourseService {

public Course findCourseById(Integer id);

public Course updateCourse(Course course);

public Course createCourse(Course course);

public void deleteCourse(Course course);

public List<Course> getAllCourses();

public List<Course> getAllCoursesByCategory(String category);

public List<Course> getAllCoursesWhichNoProposal( );

}
```

CourseServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class CourseServiceImpl implements CourseService {
@Autowired
private CoursesDAO coursesDAOImpl;


@Transactional
public Course findCourseById(Integer id) {

    Course course = coursesDAOImpl.findCourseById(id);

    return course;
}
@Transactional
public Course updateCourse(Course course) {

    // Course.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();

    course = coursesDAOImpl.updateCourse(course);

    // Course.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    return course;
}
@Transactional
public Course createCourse(Course course) {

      //Course.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();

    course = coursesDAOImpl.createCourse(course);

      //Course.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    return course;
}
@Transactional
public List<Course> getAllCourses() {

    // Course.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();

    List<Course> listCourses = coursesDAOImpl.getAllCourses();

    // Course.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    return listCourses;
}
@Transactional
public List<Course> getAllCoursesByCategory(String category) {

    // Course.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();

    List<Course> listCoursesByCategory = coursesDAOImpl
            .getAllCoursesByCategory(category);

    // Course.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    return listCoursesByCategory;
}

@Transactional
public List<Course> getAllCoursesWhichNoProposal( ) {

    // Course.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();

    List<Course> listCoursesNoProposal = coursesDAOImpl
            .getAllCoursesWhichNoProposal( );

    // Course.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    return listCoursesNoProposal;
}
@Transactional
public void deleteCourse(Course course) {
    coursesDAOImpl.deleteCourse(course);

};
```

application-contex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/~/QWE;INIT=create schema if not exists QWE\;"
    p:username="sa"
    p:password="" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">   
    <props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
<prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop> 
<prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">QWE</prop>
</props>    
</property> 

<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <value>com.epam.edu.jtc.entity.User</value>
    <value>com.epam.edu.jtc.entity.Category</value>
    <value>com.epam.edu.jtc.entity.Course</value>
    <value>com.epam.edu.jtc.entity.UserCourse</value>
    <value>com.epam.edu.jtc.entity.ManagerCourse</value>
     </list>
 </property>
 </bean>        

<!-- FreeMarker Configuration -->
<bean id="freemarkerEmailConfig" class="freemarker.template.Configuration">
<property name="directoryForTemplateLoading" value="WEB-INF/pages/templates" />
<property name="objectWrapper">
    <bean class="freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper"/>
</property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>   
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.edu.jtc" />

</beans>
```

Comment: can you post your spring-hibernate configuration

Comment: I showed application-context.xml

Comment: why have you commented out the   <context:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>  ? how is spring supposed to gather up your annotated classes/methods?

Comment: also this line should not work as it is not correct , please check this tutorial here : http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example  , you need to add the tx tags and you should remove this line from sessionFactory config <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> otherwise spring tx manager will not wrap correctly your annotated classes in order to pass a managed session

Comment: removed <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> ? Now is exception org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread..    in line - Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Comment: ok then you dont configure smth correctly . Place the current_session back , and try open up the logs in DEBUG to check whether spring's transaction manager is wrapping your DAO's. It would print a line for each method that gets wrapped for Transactional annotation . If you dont see any line , then youll have to place the Transactional annotation to your Service Layer and not to DAO Layer

Comment: well from the last edit you posted , it should be operating properly if you remove the current_session. If still you got problems then the last thing you havent shared , is from where you are accessing your services ? i mean you autowire them properly .... ? also are you on an Application Server or plain Spring Boot ?

Answer (score 1):

I think here you have a problem of concept.

The proper architecture would be to have a transactional service that invoke a repository. Something like this.

```
@Service
public class CoursesServiceImpl implements CoursesService {

  @Autowired
  private CoursesDAO coursesDAO;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void insertCourses(Course courses) {
    coursesDAO.createCourse(courses);
  }
```

}

Then your repository

```
@Repository
public class CoursesDAOImpl implements CoursesDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Course createCourse(Course course) {

   Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    Integer id = (Integer) session.save(course);
    course.setId(id);
    //session.getTransaction().commit();

    return course;
};
```

Comment: Plus 1 for annotating on the service level

Comment: I didn't understand it ("Plus 1 for annotating on the service level")

Answer (score 0):

After setting a correct transaction manager, just tried to move the @Transactional  annotation to the method on the implemented class

```
    @Repository
    public class CoursesDAOImpl implements CoursesDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional 
public Course createCourse(Course course) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 flaws in your configuration.

First when using `@Transactional` you also have to make this clear to your configuration by including a `<tx:annotation-driven />` tag in your application context file. If not your `@Transactional` is going to do nothing.

Simple add `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager/>`, as you named it different then `transactionManager` (the default name). Of course you would also have to add the correct xsd to the header to make the `tx` namespace available.

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

and add this to your `schemaLocation` attribute.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

Second you have configured the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property in your hibernate configuration. This breaks proper integration with spring which sets it to a custom Spring class, however your setting overrides this. Remove this property.

Another thing to consider is that the actual transactional boundary should be your service layer and not your data access layer. Your service method is an all or nothing operation, if you have 3 database calls they should all participate in the same transaction. With your setup you will get 3 individual transactions, which can leave your database in an undesired state when doing multiple updates for instance. I suggest to move the `@Transactional` to your service layer instead of the data access layer.